# Загрузить swf файл из flash приложения.

Tags: flash, actionscript, swf

Как загузить правильно swf приложение и отобразить его в глваном приложение. Проще говоря, обвернуть его в flash приложение.
Делаю так

```
package  {  
        import flash.display.*;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;

        public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

            public function MainClass() {
                var loadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://path/to/file/loadfile.swf');
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.load(loadURL);
                addChild(loader);
            }
        }

    }
```

Проигрывается только звук, а самой флешки не видно, просто белое окошко.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Не удается вызвать свойство или метод со ссылкой на объект "null".
at Main()
```

Comment: Возможно еще нарушение политик безопасности, запустите в дебаг версии плеера, там возможно выдаст описание ошибки.

Comment: Ну дак флешка то загружается, только не показывается, а музыка от неё играет

Comment: музыка и графика с кодом, разные по уровню политик

Comment: http://upwap.ru/d/2962668/05145d3aa259e6aba8781e0050e9f040/6a4449d699.swf

Comment: все таки там блокировка, у меня тоже ни в какую не грузит
при это в обычном плеере играет без проблем
в программе AS3 Sorcerer этот загрузчик виден в конструкторе Main

Comment: Спасибо, что помог разобраться :)

Comment: Не за что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам MainClass добавлен на stage ?

play() ->  Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE ? (проигрывание после добавления)

Выложить тестовый файл возможно?

может размер задать "насильно" попробовать

```
loader.width = loader.heigth = 100;
loader.x = loader.y = 0;
```

Возможно еще нарушение политик безопасности, запустите в дебаг версии плеера, там возможно выдаст описание ошибки.

Comment: я вообще в первые открыл для себя ActionScript.
Есть contaner.fla и есть MainClass.as.
Куда жать, чтобы добаввить событие ADDED_TO_STAGE ? и как? )

Comment: примерно так:

    public function MainClass() 
    {
       this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addHandler );
    }

    public function addHandler( event:Event = null ):void
    {
        addChild( loader );
    }

Comment: package  {
 
 import flash.display.*;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.navigateToURL;
 import flash.events.Event;
 
 public class MainClass extends MovieClip {
   var loadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://тутаурлдофлаш');
   var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  public function MainClass() {
   this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  }
  function init(event:Event = null):void {
   loader.load(loadURL);
   addChild(loader);
  }
 }
 
}

Тоже самое, просто проигрывается звук.

Comment: а если дождаться загрузки ?  

    Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

можно глянуть на загружаемый файл ?

Comment: загружаемый файл, обычная игрушка на староннем сервере.

Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); тоже не помогло (

Comment: а, ну так там наверняка блокировка

Comment: не должно, я это приложение загрузил в ВК. Т.е. у меня есть SWF файл этого приложения

Comment: тогда без файла не скажу точно

может размер задать "насильно" попробовать

    loader.width = loader.heigth = 100;
    loader.x = loader.y = 0;